# Javascript - how to increment values on unique keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, increment

I'm trying to make an array with unique keys and assigned incremented values, in order to end up with a weighted list.

In *PHP*, I do it like this...

```
$crit1 = ['a','b','c'];
$crit2 = ['c','d','e'];
$weight = [];
foreach ( $crit1 as $item ) {$weight[$item] += 1;}
foreach ( $crit2 as $item ) {$weight[$item] += 2;}   
// print_r($weight); => array([a] => 1 [b] => 1 [c] => 3 [d] => 2 [e] => 2)
```

...with 'c' ending up with the most points: 1 for showing up in the first foreach and another 2 for being featured in the second.

Trying to translate this to *JS*...

```
const crit1 = ['a','b','c'];
const crit2 = ['c','d','e'];
let weight = [];   
crit1.forEach(function (item) { weight.push({ [item]: +1 }) });
crit2.forEach(function (item) { weight.push({ [item]: +2 }) });
// console.log(weight) => [{ a: 1}, { b: 1}, { c: 1}, { c: 2}, { d: 2}, { e: 2}]
```

...no longer works – the values for 'c' are assigned separately so the array comes up with 6 items instead of just 5.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use an object instead of an array

Comment: The JavaScript `array.push` operation (which appends to an array) is not analogous to PHP's array insertion (where a PHP array is actually an ordered map). Use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or basic [JavaScript object](https://javascript.info/object).

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @0stone0 it's indicated in the PHP example

Comment: @0stone0 `console.log(weight)` => `[{ a: 1}, { b: 1}, { c: 3}, { d: 2}, { e: 2}]`

Comment: @lucian Are you sure you want an array of objects? Your PHP example seems to indicate `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 3, d: 2, e: 2}`

Comment: anything is good enough, I'll sort it out later (in descending order / arrays work best for that in js I guess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of an array, use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) so the keys value can be bumped
2. Since we're using an object, we can't use `push`, but we'll need to address the key
3. ```
   weight[item] = (weight[item] || 0) + 1)
   ```

   Increments the current `item` key in the `weight` object by `1`, if it's not defined yet, we set it to `0`.

```js
const crit1 = ['a','b','c'];
const crit2 = ['c','d','e'];
let weight = {};   

crit1.forEach((item) => weight[item] = (weight[item] || 0) + 1);
crit2.forEach((item) => weight[item] = (weight[item] || 0) + 2);

let arr = Object.keys(weight).reduce((prev, cur) => [ ...prev, { [cur]: weight[cur] } ], []);

console.log(weight);
console.log(arr);
```

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 1,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 2,
  "e": 2
}
```

---

If you really want an array containing objects with just a single key, as shown in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70837640/javascript-how-to-increment-values-on-unique-keys/70837808#comment125229999_70837640), we can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do the conversion:

```js
let arr = Object.keys(weight).reduce((prev, cur) => [ ...prev, { [cur]: weight[cur] } ], []);
```

Will produce:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1
  },
  {
    "b": 1
  },
  {
    "c": 3
  },
  {
    "d": 2
  },
  {
    "e": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! (+other js stuff is also starting to make sense to me now :D)

Comment: array indeed. then I sort it like this:
`let top = arr.map(Object.entries).sort(([a], [b]) => b[1] - a[1]).map(([[name]]) => name).slice(0,3)`